# Different hyphenation decisions by different versions of pdfLaTeX

Tags: pdftex, hyphenation

I'm finding the same file compiling differently on two different versions of pdfLaTeX on different machines that I use. In particular, one version is willing to hyphenate, and the other is not, instead producing overfull hboxes. This is still the case for a minimal document with no packages loaded.

The first version identifies itself as pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050), and the second as pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018).

What's the reason for the difference? Is there something simple I can do to cause the second system to hyphenate the way the first one does?

Here's the document (please ignore the misformed quotation marks etc):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

The construction by Alfa and Bethe is written in terms of a system of
queues in tandem (or so-called "multiline diagrams"), and uses time
reversal arguments.
A different approach, but exploiting a related recursive structure,
was then found by Gamow, Dexter, and Epsom to give a representation of
the stationary distribution of the $N$-type TASEP using the matrix 
product ansatz.

This matrix product representation was then extended in further 
studies by Ziether, Ethier and Threaker. They asked whether the
additional compartmentalised construction of (2) could also be 
generalised to the ASEP. In this paper we show that it can.

\end{document}
```

Here's the result from the first version (TeX Live):
[image]
Here's the result from the second version (MiXTeX):
[image]

Here's the output from the first version (TeX Live) (with some spurious linebreaks):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)
(preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode 
(./minimal.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo)) 
(./minimal.aux)
[1{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./minimal.aux) )</usr/share/texlive/texmf- 
dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmmi10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf- 
dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.
pfb>
Output written on minimal.pdf (1 page, 26827 bytes).
Transcript written on minimal.log.
```

Here's the output from the second version (MiKTeX):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050)
entering extended mode
(minimal.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 2

("/Users/martin/Library/Application 
Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/bas
e/article.cls"
Document Class: article 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class

("/Users/martin/Library/Application 
Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/size11.clo")) 
(minimal.aux)
Overfull \hbox (20.49776pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 20--30
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 structure, was then found by Gamow, Dexter, and 
Epsom to give a representation

Overfull \hbox (52.13623pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 31--39
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10.95 by Ziether, Ethier and Threaker. They asked whether 
the additional compartmentalised
[1{/Users/martin/Library/Application 
Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/data/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (minimal.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information) . 
</Users/martin/Library/Application 
Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmmi10.pfb></Users/martin/Library/Application 
Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on minimal.pdf (1 page, 27929 bytes).
Transcript written on minimal.log.
```

Comment: Don't use minimal.cls for such tests, normally it is too minimal. Beside this: there was a bug in miktex regarding languages, https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/435. Run the update manager as admin and user and try again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: The OP just called the file `minimal.tex`, but uses `article`.

Comment: @Werner ups ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That did indeed solve the problem! Thanks! (The updates also seem to have broken some unrelated things, to do with including pdf images... but that's for tomorrow to sort out....)